# Devolver todos los 0 de una consulta MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estimada comunidad, tengo la siguiente consulta en MySql:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`totalPlano`),0) totalDiraio 
FROM `comprasrealizadasweb` 
WHERE `fechaTransaccion` LIKE '%2022/02/01%'
```

Funciona, pero el problema es de que cuando le hago UNION y envío más pero en diferentes fechas estoy necesitando que me devuelva todos los 0 correspondientes a los días que no hubieron ventas y que su valor es NULL.

Aquí un ejemplo claro:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`totalPlano`),0) totalDiraio 
FROM `comprasrealizadasweb` 
WHERE `fechaTransaccion` LIKE '%2022/02/01%' 
UNION 
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`totalPlano`),0) totalDiraio 
FROM `comprasrealizadasweb` 
WHERE `fechaTransaccion` LIKE '%2022/02/02%' 
UNION 
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`totalPlano`),0) totalDiraio 
FROM `comprasrealizadasweb` 
WHERE `fechaTransaccion` LIKE '%2022/02/03%' 
UNION 
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`totalPlano`),0) totalDiraio 
FROM `comprasrealizadasweb` 
WHERE `fechaTransaccion` LIKE '%2022/02/04%'
```

Esa consulta devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podemos observar únicamente devuelve o mejor dicho transforma el NULL de la primera consulta en 0, luego se los vuelve a saltar y muestra únicamente los valores de las fechas en las cuales si se percibieron ventas, espero que me puedan ayudar con este tema, saludo.

Comment: Y si son datos de la misma tabla, con los mismo campos... No sería mejor poner un OR en la condición para obtener datos que se correspondan con las fechas indicadas?

Comment: Sugieres cambiar el UNION por un OR verdad?, claro lo voy a tomar en cuenta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En vez de usar el **operador union** debes usar el **operador union all**, la diferencia está en que **union** elimina los valores duplicados, mientras que **union all** incluye todos los registros aunque estén duplicados.